# Why is 4 not an instance of Number?

Tags: javascript

Just curious:

- 4 instanceof Number => false
- new Number(4) instanceof Number => true?

Why is this? Same with strings:

- `'some string' instanceof String` returns false
- `new String('some string') instanceof String` => true
- `String('some string') instanceof String` also returns false
- `('some string').toString instanceof String` also returns false

For object, array or function types the instanceof operator works as expected. I just don't know how to understand this.

[**new insights**]

```
Object.prototype.is = function() {
        var test = arguments.length ? [].slice.call(arguments) : null
           ,self = this.constructor;
        return test ? !!(test.filter(function(a){return a === self}).length)
               : (this.constructor.name ||
                  (String(self).match ( /^function\s*([^\s(]+)/im )
                    || [0,'ANONYMOUS_CONSTRUCTOR']) [1] );
}
// usage
var Newclass = function(){};  // anonymous Constructor function
var Some = function Some(){}; // named Constructor function
(5).is();                     //=> Number
'hello world'.is();           //=> String
(new Newclass()).is();        //=> ANONYMOUS_CONSTRUCTOR
(new Some()).is();            //=> Some
/[a-z]/.is();                 //=> RegExp
'5'.is(Number);               //=> false
'5'.is(String);               //=> true
```

Comment: you have to use `Number.prototype.isPrototypeOf(inp)` - your way would also work if done correctly: `inp.constructor === Number`; it might fail, because `constructor` is just a property of the prototype and can be overwritten!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean with 'can be overwritten'. It doesn't mean I can overwrite the constructor with some other constructor (tried it). Number.prototype.isPrototypeOf(4) returns false by the way, so I can't use that for checking the type of primitive values, am I right?

Comment: That was the whole point (primitive !== wrapped primitive)! Checking constructors is dangerous because of `obj['constructor'] = ???` works! I'd suggest using my `typeOf()` function; to treat primitives and wrapped primitives the same, use `if(typeOf(x).toLowerCase() === 'string')`

Comment: In my experience assigning anything to Obj.constructor doesn't change its Constructor. As a matter of fact such assignment seems to do nothing at all. ('hellowrld').constructor = Number still returns String with getType.

Comment: Tried your typeOf of course and yes, it worked for the primitive types. I wanted 1 function for all types, primitive or not. Will try to break getType, if I can't I suppose it's usable.

Comment: Did you test your getType() function? It always returns 'undefined', except when the argument actually was `undefined` - then, it returns 'null'! Also, check http://joost.zeekat.nl/constructors-considered-mildly-confusing.html for details on how `constructor` is resolved!

Comment: Yes, I tested it and yes broke it (it's browser dependent. Only worked with jscript (thus: IE), not in other browsers, not to my surprise of course). Did a browsers test, rewrote the function and edited this question again.

Comment: it's called a leaky abstraction. JS actually has 2 kinds of objects, one kind is tagged union of types(google VARIANT for one JScript uses), and another being a tagged union of types which is specifically an object(in JScript, being IDispatch/IDispatchEx). Since only Objects are "instances", instanceof doesn't try doing extra work trying to case-by-case determine/table lookup to find a compatible type that is capable of managing it. My guess is that it's a can of worms with no known right answer at the time of design, so they chose the most honest/flexible approach.

Comment: although the simple fix is `Object(4) instanceof Number` succeeds. likewise `null instanceof Object` fails, whereas `Object(null) instanceof Object` succeeds. Given such a simple fix, i can understand why it is reasonable to not implement automatic wrapping into Object into instanceof. It makes typeof just that little bit faster.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

`value instanceof Constructor` is the same as `Constructor.prototype.isPrototypeOf(value)` and both check the [[Prototype]]-chain of `value` for occurences of a specific object.

Strings and numbers are **primitive values**, not objects and therefore don't have a [[Prototype]], so it'll only work if you wrap them in regular objects (called 'boxing' in Java).

Also, as you noticed, `String(value)` and `new String(value)` do different things: If you call the constructor functions of the built-in types without using the `new` operator, they try to convert ('cast') the argument to the specific type. If you use the `new` operator, they create a wrapper object.

`new String(value)` is roughly equivalent to `Object(String(value))`, which behaves the same way as `new Object(String(value))`.

---

Some more on types in JavaScript: ECMA-262 defines the following primitive types: *Undefined*, *Null*, *Boolean*, *Number*, and *String*. Additionally, there is the type *Object* for things which have properties.

For example, functions are of type *Object* (they just have a special property called [[Call]]), and `null` is a primitive value of type *Null*. This means that the result of the `typeof` operator doesn't really return the type of a value...

Aditionally, JavaScript objects have another property called [[Class]]. You can get it via `Object.prototype.toString.call(value)` (this will return `'[object`*`Classname`*`]'`). Arrays and functions are of the type *Object*, but their classes are *Array* and *Function*.

The test for an object's class given above works when `instanceof` fails (e.g. when objects are passed between window/frame boundaries and don't share the same prototypes).

---

Also, you might want to check out this improved version of `typeof`:

```
function typeOf(value) {
    var type = typeof value;

    switch(type) {
        case 'object':
        return value === null ? 'null' : Object.prototype.toString.call(value).
            match(/^\[object (.*)\]$/)[1]

        case 'function':
        return 'Function';

        default:
        return type;
    }
}
```

For primitives, it will return their **type** in *lower case*, for objects, it will return their **class** in *title case*.

**Examples:**

- For primitives of  **type** *Number* (eg `5`), it will return `'number'`, for wrapper objects of **class** *Number* (eg `new Number(5)`), it will return `'Number'`;
- For functions, it will return `'Function'`.

If you don't want to discern between primitive values and wrapper objects (for whatever, probably bad reason), use `typeOf(...).toLowerCase()`.

Known bugs are some built-in functions in IE, which are considered `'Object'` and a return value of `'unknown'` when used with some COM+ objects.

Comment: @annakata: check ECMA-262 . the types are called Undefined, Null, Boolean, Number, String and Object; doesn't matter what `typeof` returns...

Comment: @Christoph - it very much matters since the wrapper objects are uppercase, and the typeofs are lowercase and nothing else is accessible. The convention and practice is therefore to refer to the datatypes in the lowercase as made clear here: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/JS/Glossary

Comment: @annakata: `typeof` is broken - its return value has nothing to do with the actual types!

Comment: Well I guess you're going with the spec and I'm going with the practice, which in this case I think is in the right. I think it's ill-advised to reference the types and the wrapper objects with the same format, but I'll not edit your post further.

Comment: I contest `Strings and numbers are primitive values, not objects and therefore don't have a [[Prototype]]` Sample: `(new Number(123)).__proto__ == (123).__proto__; // true`

Comment: Your link to `my improved version of typeof` is dead

Comment: [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) indicate "The instanceof operator tests the presence of constructor.prototype in object's prototype chain."  `Object.getPrototypeOf(4) === Number.prototype` returns true. Even then `4 instanceof Number` returns false. This is the confusing part.

Comment: Strings and numbers are definitely objects.

Answer (score 20):

You may try to evaluate:

```
>>> typeof("a")
"string"
>>> typeof(new String("a"))
"object"
>>> typeof(4)
"number"
>>> typeof(new Number(4))
"object"
```

Answer (score 3):

As stated in Christoph's answer, string and number literals are not the same as String and Number objects. If you use any of the String or Number methods on the literal, say

```
'a string literal'.length
```

The literal is temporarily converted to an object, the method is invoked and the object is discarded.
Literals have some distinct advantages over objects.

```
//false, two different objects with the same value
alert( new String('string') == new String('string') ); 

//true, identical literals
alert( 'string' == 'string' );
```

Always use literals to avoid unexpected behaviour!
You can use Number() and String() to typecast if you need to:

```
//true
alert( Number('5') === 5 )

//false
alert( '5' === 5 )
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a nuance of Javascript which I've found catches some out.  The `instanceof` of operator will always result in false if the LHS is not an `object` type.

Note that `new String('Hello World')` does not result in a `string` type but is an `object`.  The `new` operator always results in an object.  I see this sort of thing:

```
function fnX(value)
{
     if (typeof value == 'string')
     {
          //Do stuff
     }
}
fnX(new String('Hello World'));
```

The expectation is that "`Do Stuff`" will happen but it doesn't because the typeof the value is object.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of primitive numbers, the `isNaN` method could also help you.

Answer (score 1):

To check if the given number is an instance of Number Class

We need to use the Object Prototype chain.

```
Object(n) instanceof Number
```

`true` if it is a Number, in this case 4.