# Why can't I get an object prototype name in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

When I run the following code:

```
var os = require('os');
var sys= require('sys');

var ostype = os.type() + " ";
sys.puts(ostype.prototype.toString());
sys.puts("\n");
```

I get the following error:

```
node.js:116
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
        ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'toString' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/Maria Dillon/test.js:5:27)
    at Module._compile (module.js:374:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:380:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:306:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:272:10)
    at Array.<anonymous> (module.js:393:10)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:108:26)
```

If I understand 15.2.4.2 of ECMA-262 3rd edition, this should work.

PS I am running node.js 0.5.0pre which I built myself on Cygwin.

Comment: I get no errors when I run your code in node -- is there more to your script than that function declaration?

Comment: Sorry, but I flubbed the cutnpaste and posted completely different code.

Comment: I got to this question by misreading an error message. In the end I moved the startsWith function to the top of the code and the following line now works fine: if (os.type().startsWith("CYGWIN")) {

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `ostype` is an `string`, which is a primitive value. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472418/why-is-4-not-an-instance-of-number#472427) you'll find more information about it.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, that explained it. In particular the improved version of typeof in that answer.