# What are the circumstances when toString works on a date while toISOString does not work?

Tags: javascript, function

Works:

```
const date = new Date();
temp = date.toISOString();
```

Doesn't work:

```
const date = new Date();
temp = date.setDate(date.getDate() - date.getDay()).toISOString();
```

Works too:

```
const date = new Date();
temp = date.setDate(date.getDate() - date.getDay()).toString();
```

What may be the reason for toISOString() not working?

Comment: `setDate` doesn't return a Date object, it returns a number.   So a number has a toString, but it doesn't have a toISOString.

Comment: `setDate` returns a number, not a `Date`. Every type has a `toString` method, only `Date`s have a `toISOString`.

Comment: So how do I convert the number (which is actually a date as a number) into a date? toDate doesn't seem to work!

Comment: `date.setDate(...); temp = date.toISOString()`. You simply can't *chain* these two actions.

Comment: I didn't recognize that. I'm so sorry. Now, I see. Thank you very much.

Comment: How may I improve this question (in order to get back asking priviliges)? I don't have a clue. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `.toString()` can be called on almost any value while `.toISOString()` can only be called on [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) objects<sup>1</sup>.

This code:

```js
const date = new Date();
temp = date.setDate(date.getDate() - date.getDay()).toISOString();
```

is effectively the same as

```js
const date = new Date();
const setDateReturnValue = date.setDate(date.getDate() - date.getDay());
setDateReturnValue.toISOString();
```

Note that `date` and `setDateReturnValue` hold two different values. The `date` is the [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object and `setDateReturnValue` is the return value of [`Date.prototype.setDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate), which is a number.

A number doesn't have a `.toISOString()` method, which is what is causing the error. A `Date` does have a `.toISOString()` method, which is why your first code snippet works fine.

Both a `Date` and a number have a `.toString()` method<sup>2</sup>, which is why those work fine, but do realize that the string they return is different in a different format. (The number will return the number as a string, where the date will return something like "Wed Sep 07 2022 16:17:40 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)")

<sup>[1]: Unless of course you or a library defines this function for different types.</sup>
<sup>[2]: Technically speaking: a number a primitive and as such, doesn't have a `.toString()` method (or any method for that matter), but when calling a method on a number, [it will be boxed into a `Number` object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40491240/why-in-javascript-does-3-instanceof-number-false-but-3-method-will), which does have a `.toString()` method.</sup>

Comment: When I try your code, it's telling me: setDateReturnValue.toISOString is not a function. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @MightyA That's what I said in the answer. "_`setDateReturnValue` is the return value of `Date.prototype.setDate()`, which is a number_" and "_A number doesn't have a `.toISOString()` method, which is what is causing the error._". If you want to call `.toISOString()`. you'll have to call it on `date`.