# Are symbols acting like objects in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Are symbols acting like objects in JavaScript or a Symbol object is being created under the hood in the following example:

```
const symbol = Symbol();

Symbol.prototype.sayHello = function () {
  console.log("sayHello");
};

symbol.sayHello(); //"sayHello"
```

I know that in JavaScript the function Symbol cannot be invoked with the keyword "new". But can it be done behind the scenes? I already know that when we use methods on primitive values like this:

```
console.log("333".startsWith("33")); //true
```

A String object is being created and the method String.prototype.startsWith is being invoked. After that, the object is being garbage-collected. But is it the same case when we work with symbols? Even though we cannot explicitly invoke the function Symbol as a constructor function?

Comment: Yes, it’s exactly the same with symbols; they’re primitive types, and you can still do `Object(Symbol())`.

Comment: `new Symbol` is disallowed for other reasons. You can try searching for some very old TC39 proposal texts (keywords “tc39 harmony wiki strawman”). For example: [the 2013-09 meeting notes](//archives.ecma-international.org/2013/notes/2013-09/sept-18.html#44-symbols): _“DD: `new Symbol()` is a probable footgun; should it do anything at all? Maybe just throw? Because we don't have symbol literals, so unlike `new Number(5)` vs. `Number(5)` vs. `5`, the choice is not obvious; people will try to do `new Symbol()` not realizing that this creates a wrapper.”_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, symbols are [primitive values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9108925/1048572), and invoking methods on them works just like for [strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5751704/1048572) or [numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40491240/1048572) -  a wrapper object gets implicitly created that inherits from `Symbol.prototype`.

You cannot create such a wrapper object using `new Symbol`, but you still can create it by calling

```
const symbol = Symbol();
const wrapper = Object(symbol);
```