# Why a number isn't instance of Number with typeof and instanceof?

Tags: javascript

I need to take all elements of given type from an array, like this `[{ a: 'a' }, 4, /a-z/, 6, [1, 2, 3], i=>i]`, and when I provide type Number as argument to ofType(type) it returns [ ] :

```
Array.prototype.ofType = function (type) {
    let newArr = []; 
    this.forEach(i => i instanceof type ? newArr.push(i) : newArr );
    return newArr
}
```

in other cases , like `[{ a: 'a' }, 4, /a-z/, 6, [1, 2, 3], i=>i].ofType(RegExp)` it works correctly.

Comment: Primitives are not instances of anything. Use `Object.prototype.toString.call(var)` to find the "class" of the variable, `var` here is the target you want to check the type of.

Comment: As a side note, it's usually a very bad idea to modify the built-in prototypes. Also, you seem to be looking for a formalised version of `.filter` -> `.filter(ofType(Number))` where `ofType = type => x => x instanceOf type`

Comment: **See Also**: [Why is 4 not an instance of Number?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/472418/1366033)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript has number *primitives* and Number *objects*. A number primitive isn't `instanceof` anything because it isn't an object, and only objects are "instances" of something ("instance" being a term of art from object oriented programming); so `instanceof` is not useful for primitives.

That's where `typeof` comes in. The result of `typeof` for primitive numbers is `"number"`.

Since `instanceof` expects a constructor function as the right hand operand, you could have your `ofType` function branch based on whether it gets a function or a string, using `instanceof` if it's a function and `typeof` if it's a string. Using your `forEach` loop:

```
Array.prototype.ofType = function (type) {
    let newArr = []; 
    if (typeof type === "string") {
        this.forEach(i => typeof i === type ? newArr.push(i) : newArr );
    } else {
        this.forEach(i => i instanceof type ? newArr.push(i) : newArr );
    }
    return newArr;
};
```

But I wouldn't use `forEach` for this, I'd use `filter`:

```
Array.prototype.ofType = function (type) {
    let newArr;
    if (typeof type === "string") {
        newArr = this.filter(i => typeof i === type);
    } else {
        newArr = this.filter(i => i instanceof type);
    }
    return newArr;
};
```

Also, I strongly recommend **not** adding enumerable properties to `Array.prototype`, it breaks code that incorrectly uses `for-in` loops on arrays. Use `Object.defineProperty` instead:

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "ofType", {
    value(type) {
        let newArr;
        if (typeof type === "string") {
            newArr = this.filter(i => typeof i === type);
        } else {
            newArr = this.filter(i => i instanceof type);
        }
        return newArr;
    },
    writable: true,
    configurable: true,
    enumerable: false // This is the default, so you could leave it off
});
```

Live Example:

```js
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "ofType", {
    value(type) {
        let newArr;
        if (typeof type === "string") {
            newArr = this.filter(i => typeof i === type);
        } else {
            newArr = this.filter(i => i instanceof type);
        }
        return newArr;
    },
    writable: true,
    configurable: true,
    enumerable: false // This is the default, so you could leave it off
});

console.log([1, "2", 3, "4"].ofType("number"));

console.log([new Date, "2", new Date, "4"].ofType(Date));
```

Answer (score 1):

Only *objects* can have `instanceof <something>` evaluate to `true`. Whenever you have

```
x instanceof y
```

if `x` is not an object, it will always evaluate to `false`. This is described in the specification [here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ordinaryhasinstance):

> If Type(O) is not Object, return false.

If you use a number *object* rather than just a number, it'll work as expected and evaluate to true:

```js
console.log(
  (new Number(5)) instanceof Number
);
```

If you want to check if something is a particular primitive value, use `typeof` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript has Objects (i.e. new Number(), Array, Regexp, ....) and Primitives ('string', 1, true). `instanceof` just works for objects. Because of this your number, which is a primitive, cannot be tested with `instanceof`.

Please checkout the function `toType`. Here the generic version of `toString` with the help of JavaScript's `call`-method is used to get the class of the corresponding variable. It solves your issue in a casual manner. Checkout following snippet:

```js
let data = [{ a: 'a' }, 4, /a-z/, 6, [1, 2, 3], i=>i, new Number(5)];

Array.prototype.ofType = function (type) {

  let toType = function(obj) {
    return ({}).toString.call(obj).match(/\s([a-zA-Z]+)/)[1].toLowerCase()
  }

  return this.filter((item) => {
    return toType(item) === type;
  });
}

console.log(data.ofType('number'));
console.log(data.ofType('array'));
console.log(data.ofType('regexp'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the variables *constructor* to determine the type (can be used for primitives and Objects alike), and filter the `Array` on it. Something like:

```js
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "ofType", {
  value(isType = Number) {
    return this.filter(v => v.constructor === isType);
  },
  writable: true,
  configurable: true,
});

console.log([{a: 'a'}, 4, /a-z/, 6, [1, 2, 3], i => i].ofType());
console.log([{a: 'a'}, 4, /a-z/, 6, [1, 2, 3], i => i].ofType(RegExp));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  top: 0;
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Note that checking `constructor` does not (necessarily) match all descendants. If you have `B extends A` then doing `ofType(A)` will only produce `A` and filter out `B`

Comment: Noted. I never use the `class` sugar stuff and seldom feel the need to extend things

Comment: To be fair, it's class hierarchies usually tend to be shallow and in JavaScript even more. It's not exactly a class hierarchy, either since it's all prototypal inheritance anyway. You *could* even have *effectively* `B extends A` but `B` uses the constructor of `A`, in which case checking the `constructor` property would work. Still, I just wanted to note the difference between the constructor and `instanceof` - the latter checks the whole prototype chain.

Comment: Mmm, you can always add a getter (`get super() {return super.constructor;}`) to a class that extends another, if you want to be able to investigate the class hierarchy.